# Best Android phones for testing

Tags: android

Can anyone suggest good performance 3 android phones btw 15k-20k,for testing purposes....i need to test some apps related to wifi and some basic stuff..Thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for specific programming questions.. It doesn't offer recommendations.. Please read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: yes of course.....bt as i am new to android..i needed to know about few testing devices..

Comment: This is an entirely valid question for Stack Overflow -- nothing in the FAQ prevents offering recommendations for best Droid phones for development any more than it prevents offering recommendations for best coding practices. It's valid even if the questioner is re-directed to more appropriate pages for such a discussion, as e.g: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80694/how-do-i-choose-an-android-phone-for-testing-my-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by `15k-20k,` ? in USD or INR or LKR???

For testing purpose, you better buy a Nexus device from the [Nexus family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Nexus). They run the OS as it is released by the Google.

- Nexus S
- Nexus One
- Galaxy Nexus
- Nexus 4
- Nexus 7 (tablet)
- Nexus 10 (tablet)

On the other hand you may consider buying SII, SIII from Samsung as there is a huge fragment of Android market is using those mobiles.

Comment: Thanks 2 all...@mayu 15k-20k INR.

Comment: Too bad that most of the market is using heavily modified android versions instead of the Vanilla on the Nexuses.

Buying low-end Samsung, HTC, LG, Huewei or nameless chinese phones is more realistic

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the Samsung galaxy 2
Sony Xperia tipo
Sony Xperia s
Samsung galaxy ace 
Lg one
You could event try Alcatel phones
All phones are reasonably priced too

Answer (score -1):

3 android devices which i use for testing are

for a good phablet view is the Samsung Galaxy Note GT N-7000
high performance for heavy stuff LG Nexus4
the most sold phone of 2012 should have this - Samsung Galaxy s3